# how to generate smart implements function in intellij idea, not only Ctrl+O

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, editor

**when I Ctrl+O like this:**

```
public class Lists<E> implements List<E>{

    private final List<E> target;

    public Lists(List<E> target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Actually I want is this:**

```
public class Lists<E> implements List<E>{

    private final List<E>t target;

    public Lists(List<E> target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @override
    public int size() {    
      return target.size(); 
    }
}
```

except manually write, how about the automatic method

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Code | Generate | Delegate Methods will generate methods with an implementation that delegates them to one of the members (in this case, "target" field).

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-delegation-methods.html for more details.

Comment: Perfect,Thank you so much .I've found for a time